# Powershell CSV Column populated from Array

Tags: powershell, csv

Say I have a csv with this format: where "" represents a null value.

```
column1 column2 column3 column4
------- ------- ------- -------
123     555     aaa     ""
456     555     bbb     ""
789     666     ccc     ""
```

We can see the length of the rows is 3.
I have an array with 3 items that I want to populate column 4 with.

```
$arr123 = @("iii","jjj","kkk")
```

How can I use `Add-Member` to add the array values to the rows so the result would be like this?

```
column1 column2 column3 column4
------- ------- ------- -------
123     555     aaa     "iii"
456     555     bbb     "jjj"
789     666     ccc     "kkk"
```

I've tried a few things and just cant get it. One thing I tried that I thought would work is removing the column4, then tried to add it back with this.

```
for($i=4; $i -lt $myCSVvariable.Count; $i++) {
$myCSVvariable | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "column4" -Value "$arr123[$i]" -Force
 }
```

I really feel like that for loop should have done it, what did I do wrong? Are there any other approaches I can take?

Comment: how are you deciding what array item goes with what CSV row/object?

Comment: it's just an array, there's no property/member that you can add to. += adds an item to an array (by creating a new array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I totally agree with [Drew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5552766/drew) that you should somehow make sure the data you are inserting corresponds with the rest of the data in each row.

From your question, I can clearly see the fourth column is present in your example CSV. However, you are also saying *"We can see the length of the rows is 3"*. This does not match with what you show us..

**Scenario 1**
The CSV file **does** already have the fourth column with headers and looks like

> ```
> "column1","column2","column3","column4"
> "123","555","aaa",""
> "456","555","bbb",""
> "789","666","ccc",""
> "321","777","ddd",""
> ```

Then this should do what you want:

```
$csv    = Import-Csv 'D:\yourdata.csv'
$arr123 = "iii","jjj","kkk"

# figure out the minimum lenght for the loop, so we don't run into 
# error: "Index was outside bounds of array"
$numItems = [math]::Min($csv.Count, $arr123.Count)

# now loop through the rows and insert the data by index
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $numItems; $i++) {
    $csv[$i].column4 = $arr123[$i]
}

# show the result on screen
$csv | Format-Table -AutoSize

# or export to a new CSV file
# $csv | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\yourdata_Extended.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

---

**Scenario 2**
If however, your CSV file does **NOT** already have this fourth column and looks like

> ```
> "column1","column2","column3"
> "123","555","aaa"
> "456","555","bbb"
> "789","666","ccc"
> "321","777","ddd"
> ```

Then, you need to add a column to every row and insert the data from the array:

```
$csv    = Import-Csv 'D:\yourdata.csv'
$arr123 = "iii","jjj","kkk"

# now loop through all the CSV rows and insert a new column and array data (if available)
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $csv.Count; $i++) {
    $value = if ($i -lt $arr123.Count) { $arr123[$i] } else { $null }
    $csv[$i] | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "column4" -Value $value
}

# show the result on screen
$csv | Format-Table -AutoSize

# or export to a new CSV file
# $csv | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\yourdata_Extended.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

Both scenarios result in an updated csv (as shown on console with Format-Table -AutoSize):

> ```
> column1 column2 column3 column4
> ------- ------- ------- -------
> 123     555     aaa     iii    
> 456     555     bbb     jjj    
> 789     666     ccc     kkk    
> 321     777     ddd
> ```

<sup>P.S. For the declaration of the array `$arr123` you don't need to put the values for the elements inside a `@()` construct</sup>

Answer (score 1):

This is a slightly different approach to take as it loops throught the CSV and not the Array.

This probably isn't the best way to go about it. I would recommend looking into a Hashtable to ensure the data you are adding to the CSV matches with another column of the data.

```
# Import the CSV
$csv = import-csv C:\folder\MyCSV.csv

# Establish the Array
$arr123 = @("iii","jjj","kkk")
# Set counter for array iteration
$i = 0

# Loop through each row in CSV
Foreach($Row in $csv) {
    # Add array item based on row of CSV, assuming each row relates to the corresponding index of array
    $Row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "column4" -Value $arr123[$i] -Force
    # Increase counter
    $i++
}

# Export modifications
$csv | Export-Csv C:\folder\MyCSV.csv -NoTypeInformation
```